# Hosted Payment Session Integration in React Native

Tags: react-native, session, payment, hosted, mastercard

I am a newbie in React Native and my project has payment integration. We need to integrate Hosted Session of mastercard in our application

https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedSession/integrationModelHostedSession.html

When I studied, it stated that the html buttons for Card Number, CVV Number, Expiry Month and Year will be replaced by their iframes. Can anyone help me to know if there is a library in react native to do this hosted session integration?

Comment: Any help on this